# Goldstone modes and Anderson-Higgs mechanism in the context of BCS theory

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, higgs

I'm already familiar with the "Mexican hat" story of Anderson-Higgs mechanism in [Landau-Ginzberg theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory). However, I have never seen anyone talking about Goldstone and Higgs mechanism in the context of BCS theory of superfluidity and superconductivity. I need the answer to the following questions:

1. In a BCS superfluid, what does the Goldstone mode creation operator look like, in terms of BCS quasi-paritcle operators $\alpha_k=u_k a_k-v_k a^\dagger_{-k}$ ($a_k, a^\dagger_k$ are fermion annihilation/creation operators of momentum $k$)?
2. In BCS superconductivity, what is the operator representation of the gauge boson $A^\mu(k)$ and Higgs boson $H(k)$?

Or to put it another way, say if I want to create a [Goldstone boson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson) (with momentum $k$) in superfluid BCS ground state $|\Phi_{BCS}\rangle$, what does the resulting excited state look like?

Comment: What are you calling $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$ here, the bare fermion creation and annihilation operators? Please edit this information into your question to make it intelligible.

Comment: @MarkMitchison  Yes. Anyway I need the operator repesentation of the Goldstone and Higgs.

Comment: Goldstone and Higgs modes can be expanded in normal modes, and thus will get the usual form of creation/destruction operators. Classically, the Anderson-Higgs mode follows a massive wave equation, as can be seen from Ginzburg-Landau formalism, which you can quantise if you want. They representation from the quasi-particle is harder to give, since they are clearly dressed states. A Higgs mode is intrinsically a bosons mode dressed by the fermionic quasi-particles. You get it either by integrating out the fermionic modes in a path-integral approach in the mean-field approximation.

Comment: One more time, be careful with your nomenclature. A superfluid is a quantum condensate of neutral bosonic particles (as He-4), a BCS superfluid is a quantum condensate of neutral fermionic particles (as He-3) (in a sense, they are not spin-neutral, but remains charge-neutral), a BCS superconductor (or a superconductor in short) is a quantum condensate of charged fermionic particles (as electrons). This nomenclature is not accepted by everyone, so I suggest you to define what you mean each time you use them and want to compare these different mechanism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\def\kk{{\bf k}}
\def\rr{{\bf r}}
\def\ii{{\rm i}}
\def\ee{{\rm e}}
\def\qq{{\bf q}}$
I can't give a complete answer but I will attempt to address question 1). (To be absolutely clear, that means I will talk only about a BCS-type superfluid which is electrically neutral and therefore supports a Goldstone mode. In the charged case, the Goldstone mode is lifted to the plasma frequency by the Anderson-Higgs mechanism.) The original BCS theory actually does not contain a Goldstone mode. This is because one assumes a static condensate described by the order parameter
$$\Delta(\rr) = \frac{1}{V}\sum_{\kk,\qq} \ee^{\ii\qq\cdot\rr} \langle a_{\kk+\qq/2,\uparrow}a_{-\kk+\qq/2,\downarrow}\rangle.$$
Here I'm considering a homogeneous $s$-wave superfluid with periodic boundary conditions in a volume $V$. In the ground state, one has a spatially constant order parameter $\Delta(\rr) = {\rm const.}$, which means that Cooper pairs condense into states with zero centre-of-mass momentum $\qq =0$.

The typical BCS mean-field treatment predicts an elementary excitation spectrum consisting of gapped quasiparticles, which are created by breaking apart condensed pairs. However, in an *uncharged* superfluid, the low-energy excitations actually correspond to gapless collective oscillations of the Cooper-pair condensate, i.e. the Goldstone mode. This leads to a time- and space-varying order parameter $\Delta(\rr,t)$ describing a macroscopic number of Cooper pairs carrying non-zero centre-of-mass momentum $\qq\neq 0$. In other words, the Goldstone mode excitations correspond to the entire condensate being coherently displaced slightly in momentum space. But since in BCS theory the condensate is a classical variable (the mean field), there is no operator describing the dynamics of $\Delta(\rr,t)$. Nevertheless it is possible to compute the spectrum of its excitations using a dynamical extension of BCS theory where the mean-field is time-dependent. In the end, this procedure turns out to be equivalent to the random-phase approximation. A quite comprehensive study along these lines was done by [Combescot et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0607493).

A full quantum-mechanical treatment of the Goldstone mode can of course be performed by going beyond mean-field theory. However, usually this is done in the path integral formalism, where there are no operators whatsoever. In this case, the Goldstone mode is an excitation of a Hubbard-Stratanovich field, which is introduced in the Cooper pair channel and used to integrate out the bare fermion field. Quantum fluctuations of the pair condensate are described as Gaussian (or higher-order) fluctuations around the saddle-point describing the BCS ground state. A good original reference for this formalism is [Engelbrecht et al.](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.55.15153) and references therein (unfortunately behind a paywall), although there are many more modern treatments that can also be found by Googling. The topic of fluctuations in BCS-type neutral superfluids is currently very active because of experiments on the [BCS-BEC crossover in ultracold atomic gases](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0401554).

Comment: Does this mean that, in the original BCS mean-field treatment, only the ground state $|\Phi_{BCS}\rangle$ gives a good approximation of the true ground state of original (number-conserving) Hamiltonian; the excited states cannot be obtained by $\alpha^\dagger_k|\Phi_{BCS}\rangle$? (The BCS prediction of excitation spectrum shouldn't be taken seriously at all as it doesn't contain the Goldstone?)

Comment: @Lagrenge In the *uncharged* superfluid, yes: the BCS quasiparticle spectrum is completely wrong. But in the typical condensed-matter context (charged superconductor) the Anderson-Higgs mechanism lifts the Goldstone mode way up to the plasma frequency, so that the gapped BCS quasiparticle spectrum is still correct at low energies. Even in the uncharged case, the mean-field equations do give qualitatively correct equations of state because the thermodynamics of the superfluid phase transition is determined by the fraction of condensed pairs, and not by the collective mode excitations.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I'm surprised by your previous comment. Your answer should make it clear that a BCS superconductor does not have Goldstone mode, only Anderson-Higgs mechanism. In ultracold gases, the so-called BCS-BEC crossover is misleading, since atoms are always neutral, whereas a BCS condensate is necessarily charged. I know this is the usual nomenclature in this community, but it is completely misleading regarding the quantum field theory nomenclature. Your previous comment make this point clear, not your answer. It is unfortunate that this point is not clear in your answer.

Comment: @FraSchelle My answer addresses only question 1) about the uncharged case, precisely because I am not an expert on the Higgs mechanism. I thought it would be clear therefore that I consider only a neutral system (note the italicised "*uncharged*" and the fact that the OP already appears to be quite aware of the nonexistence of Goldstone modes in the charged system). However, to avoid any confusion I have now explicitly stated that I am only talking about neutral systems. Please let me know if this is clear. Perhaps you'd also like to add an answer discussing the Higgs mechanism?

Comment: @MarkMitchison Thank you very much fo the clarification. Indeed, I realised after writing my previous comment that the OP was clear enough in her/his question. I would add a few sentence about the Higgs field in superconductors, but I'm not aware of any study using this field in a quantum way. I do not see any difficulty with quantising the massive wave equation one gets from the Ginzburg-Landau formalism. So at the moment I prefer to stay on a comment level (see the ones I gave below the question). Thank you again for the clarification, which confuses many people I think.

Comment: @FraSchelle No problem, I'm glad that it's now clear.

Comment: @MarkMitchison "In the uncharged superfluid, yes: the BCS quasiparticle spectrum is completely wrong" I don't understand this. I thought the original paper was meant to explain even the uncharged case, and the typical meanfield treatment is often given in lecture notes (even in the absence of a higgs mechanism). For clarity, are you saying that in the classical bcs theory with no higgs, you would at finite temperature find resistance due to the collective excitations? So you have to invoke higgs for the bcs model to make sense?

Comment: @camel Well, with the benefit of 4 years' hindsight, this old comment of mine may have gone a bit far! The gapped BCS quasiparticle spectrum is correct, but in an uncharged fermionic superfluid there are other excitations as well: the gapless collective mode. As far as I understand, the main success of the original BCS paper was to explain the quasiparticle energy gap and its dependence on temperature, isotopic mass etc. So there was no problem with their neglect of the gapless collective mode (which is absent in charged systems anyway). I know little about electronic superconductors, though!

Comment: @MarkMitchison thanks for the reply! Do you know if it is possible to show that these collective modes contribute very little to the resistivity at low temperatures?

Comment: Well the famous argument explaining superfluidity (zero-resistance flow) due to Landau is predicated on a gapless excitation spectrum (see e.g. [this impromptu Google result](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1284), Sec. 2.1). So in other words, you cannot explain superfluidity in the neutral system without invoking the collective mode. Obviously *electrical* resistivity/superconductivity doesn't arise in a neutral system, which doesn't respond to electric fields at all :)

Comment: aha! so the clue is that 2particle processes are severely constrained due to both energy and momentum conservation? Am I then correct in saying that superfluids will indeed experience resistance at low temperatures, but that this process is severely supressed (coupling parameter to some power)?

Comment: @camel Hmm, I am also not an expert on superfluidity but my understanding is that flows of an ideal superfluid below a critical *velocity* experience exactly zero resistance (which is possible only when below the critical temperature for superfluid formation). Of course, real superfluids are not ideal, e.g. in a BEC one has phonon-phonon scattering which is an order $1/\sqrt{N}$ effect and usually neglected, but should lead to some dissipation. I guess the point of Landau's 2-component theory is that you may always conceptually divide the BEC into normal and (ideal) superfluid fractions.

Comment: @MarkMitchison thanks a lot, these few comments cleared things up tremendously!

Answer (score 3):

In a superfluid Bose-Einstein condensate, the Goldstone excitations are oscillating perturbations of the order parameter $\psi(\mathbf{r},t)$ above its equilibrium value $\psi_0$. In the long-wavelength limit, they are just sound waves in a superfluid, [described by a linearized Gross-Pitaevskii equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation#Bogoliubov_approximation).

In a BCS superconductor, the Goldstone modes are oscillations of a Cooper pair condensate. Because of the Coulomb interactions, these excitations are very similar to usual plasma oscillations (bulk plasmons) in a metal, as was first described by [P.W. Anderson](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.112.1900) and [G. Rickayzen](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.115.795). In 3D, these modes acquire a gapped dispersion due to long-range character of Coulomb interaction. In contrast, in 2D superconductors the Goldstone modes, as well as usual 2D plasmons, [remain gapless](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.65.1482).

Comment: Is this the reason why fluctuations kill SC in 2D? Maybe you can help me answering this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338943/

Comment: @JWDiddy I don't know much about this subject, but I think Goldstone modes don't destroy superconductivity unless they violate the Landau criterium. In 2D you need to look at vortices and related BKT transition (see, e.g., https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.1542). In 1D superconducting ordering can be absent theoretically, in infinite system, but can still be present in finite system.